# Is sqlite locked during .backup

Tags: sqlite, locking, backup

While a backup of a sqlite db is going on (via the .backup command), is the sqlite db locked to prevent writes?

This answer seems to suggest that the db is *not* locked.

[sqlite3 shell command '.backup' and transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895776/sqlite3-shell-command-backup-and-transaction)

However, I could not find a definite source in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation a shared (read-only) lock is acquired.

http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html