# safe copy of sqlite in bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite, backup

I want to implement binary backup of sqlite database inside bash script
and set this as cron job. Safe backup means write lock before copying the database file.
I found that bash interactive recipe (http://ajacevedo.com/resources/sqlite/):

```
$ sqlite3 databasename.sqlite3
sqlite> begin immediate;
<press CTRL+Z>
$ cp -a databasename.sqlite3 databasename.sqlite3.backup
$ fg
sqlite> rollback;
sqlite> .exit
```

I know that there is .backup in sqlite but it doesn't seem to do the write lock
([Is sqlite locked during .backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843044/is-sqlite-locked-during-backup)).
I am not a bash expert unfortunatelly. Is there a possibility to implement that code in bash script which can be executed as cron job (non-interactive)?
May be using pid or some other sort of magic.

Comment: I think you'll need to use `expect` to script the interaction with `sqlite3`.

Comment: This recipe will not work for an sqlite db in write-ahead logging (WAL) mode: You would need to copy the write-ahead log (the -wal file), too.

Answer (score 3):

The below command can be used inside the bash script:

```
sqlite3 your_db.sqlite ".backup your_backup.sqlite"
```

Sqlite3 queries can be written in bash, using the `sqlite3 db_name.sqlite "command"`.

`.backup` is also the safe way to make backup during the work. Good notes are mentioned here: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Answer (score 1):

Even the read lock used by `.backup` prevents anybody else from writing.

(The backup regularly drops the lock to allow other programs to run without too long waits; if any writes have happened, it resynchronizes.)